# Host failing to add to known_hosts on VPS

Tags: deployment, github, ssh, vps

I am setting up a VPS on Digital Ocean to host my simple Rails app and I am trying to run my version of this command to test the agent ssh forwarding is working:

```
ssh -A deploy@one-of-my-servers.com 'git ls-remote git@github.com:capistrano/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan.git'
```

but that fails. The Capistrano guide I am following (http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/), says, if thats fails then to do the following:

> If you get the error "host key verification failed." log in into your
>   server and run as the deploy user the command ssh git@github.com to
>   add github.com to the list of known hosts.

I do that but get:

```
$ ssh git@github.com
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.131)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/deploy/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: are you sure deploy is owner of /home/deploy/.ssh?

Comment: follow this steps: http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2014/01/deploying-rails-apps-to-a-vps-with-capistrano-v3/